# PHPUnit inheritance tests

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a parent and a child classes - loaded with spl_register_autoload()) and I'm trying to write PHPUnit tests; I have a problem with the inheritance : when I run tests, this warning message appears:

```
Warning: include(classes/PHPUnit\Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\test\test\unit_tests\test\Employe9Test.php on line 36.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The relative path to ClassLoader.class.php is not found when the file is called from Employe9Test.php

If you need an autoloader for your tests, may I suggest you to use the bootstrap property in the phpunit config file?

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <file>tests/IntlFormatterTest.php</file>
      <file>tests/MoneyTest.php</file>
      <file>tests/CurrencyTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

[Source](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/organizing-tests.html)

That way you won't have to adjust/edit the autoload file path in each of your test file if the autoload file path changes.